# Djangoのtemplate内にあるhtmlに外部のhtmlを読み込ませたい

Tags: python, django

静的なhtmlが大半を占めるwebサイトにdjangoアプリケーションを組み込もうとしています。
ディレクトリ構成は以下のようになっています。

```
root/
　├ var/
　│　 └ www/
　│　　　├ html/
　│　　　    ├ static
　│　　　    │  ├style.css
　│　　　    │  ├base.js
　│　　　    │ 
　│　　　    ├ web/
　│　　　　　     ├head.html
　│　　　　　     ├footer.html
　│　　　　　     ├base.html
　│
　└ opt/
　　　└ django/
　　　　　├ project/
　　　　　│
　　　　　├ apps/
　　　　　├　├ views.py
　　　　　 　├ template/
　　　　　 　     ├ index.html
```

djangoの/opt/django/template/index.htmlに/var/www/html/web/配下にあるhtmlを読み込ませたいのですが、includeの仕方がわかりません。
`{% include "/var/www/html/web/head.html" %}`でいけるかと思いましたが、NGでした。

静的なhtmlはcssやjsを読み込ませているので、ディレクトリ構成は崩したくないと考えています。
何かよい方法がありましたら、ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
setting.py内のTEMPLATESを以下のように編集。

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps/template'),'/var/www/html/web/']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

これにより
`{% include "head.html" %}`で読み込みできました。